Installing cert-manager for Kubernetes via Ansible gives ModuleNotFoundError
I am writing an Ansible playbook to build a Kubernetes cluster (K3S) running on 4 nodes with Raspi OS.
I am using the kubernetes.core package that can be installed in Ansible with the command:
ansible-galaxy collection install kubernetes.core

The API is found here.
I am trying to install the cert-manager repository to Helm with a task that is analogue to the command:
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io --force-update

And so far I have defined the task as:
- name: Add cert-manager Helm repository
  kubernetes.core.helm_repository:
    name: jetstack
    url: https://charts.jetstack.io
    force: true

But when I run my playbook I get the following error:
TASK [helm : Add cert-manager Helm repository]
***************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see
the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

Adding -vvv gives a little more information, but still rather obscure:
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.helm_repository_payload_tdbnu9cy/ansible_kubernetes.core.helm_repository_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/modules/helm_repository.py", line 173, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

Is there anyone who knows what is going on?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. about installation of pre-made software) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

It is not a sys admin question in the classical sence, since Kubernetes is all about full stack developing. All configurations of Kubernetes is done i YAML and the error code in the full trace hints: It is a python file that throws a tantrum saying "Module is not found". I also know that some values needs to be passed as strings. Anyway after some digging I have closed in on a solution, but I need to test it a bit, since Ansible playbook gave an error, even though I can see cert-manage was installed.

Some modules in Ansible have external dependencies which you might need t installed them on either target node or controller node(This depends on where it will going to be used). To check module dependencies, by convention, they have REQUIREMENTS field which you can check by using something like grep or awk:
ansible-doc kubernetes.core.helm_repository | awk  '/REQUIREMENTS/,/^$/'
Example:
~> ansible-doc kubernetes.core.helm_repository |  awk  '/REQUIREMENTS/,/^$/'
REQUIREMENTS:  helm (https://github.com/helm/helm/releases), yaml
        (https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/)


~> ansible-doc community.mysql.mysql_db |  awk  '/REQUIREMENTS/,/^$/'
REQUIREMENTS:  MySQLdb (Python 2.x), PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python
        3.x) or, mysql (command line binary),
        mysqlclient (Python 3.5+) or, mysqldump
        (command line binary)



keep in mind, not all of them always needed. for instance in mysql example its enough to have either of MySQLdb or PyMySQL. sometimes a dependency is used in a specific kind of task too. like mysqldump would be used just if you want to create dumps using mysql Ansible module, otherwise you don't need it.

Thank you. I did stumble upon the mention of PyYaml but I was a bit unsure if it got installed during my debugging for the answer that eventually made ansible happy. I did found out that Helm will complain if there are no file located at /root/.kube/config on the control node.

You need to install pyyaml python module. If you think it's already installed then probably you're having multiple Python versions on the ansible machine.
You can find what Python version is used by ansible with:
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.17
  ...
  configured module search path = ['/Users/v_angapov/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.18 (main, Aug 24 2023, 18:16:58) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)]

In my case Ansible is using Python 3.9.18.
Then you can try to manually import yaml module:
$ python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.18
$ python3.9 -c "import yaml"
$

See ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
I would highly recommend using python-virtualenv for ansible: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/python-venv-ansible
